# In MSTest's Test View, how can I get a list of all Tests with no category?

Tags: mstest, categories

I'm using MSTest and most of my unit tests have no `TestCategory` attribute, but I want to put a few tests into a "Slow" category.  Then I want to be able to easily run all the tests that have no category assigned.

When I go to Test View, I can filter by Test Categories, but I can't put in a keyword of empty.  I can easily find my "Slow" ones, but how to I find my non-Slow ones?  I'm trying to avoid putting a test category on all my tests.

I guess it's not the end of the world if I have to... a search and replace should get them all, but if there's a way to find the non-categorized, I would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the test list editor, add Test Categories as a column, group by None, and sort on Test Categories. Tests with no categories will be at the top. Unfortunately, you can't group by Test Category.

Comment: Right, so the answer is, "you can't".  I ended up putting a description on each one and using it as a Category, since you can group by descriptions.

Answer (score 5):

You can also exclude these tests from the command line.

```
mstest /testcontainer:foo.tests.dll /category:!Slow
```

Comment: The `/testcontainer` option is necessary in order to make `/category` option work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `/category:!Slow` doesn't work at all. Bad thing!
So it's necessary to put, for example `[TestCategory("unit")]` attribute to all of the tests.

Another, better way is to separate unit and integration tests by projects and run such tests separately.

Comment: You must use the `/testcontainer` option in order to use the `/category` option. See the [MSTest page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx).